# How to manage state running "Activity for result" for item in a list?

Tags: java, android

For example there is a list of items inside `RecyclerView`. And I want to change image for item after click on correspond list item. How to keep item `position` after `startActivityForResult`, and route image `onActivityResult` back to correspond item based on `position`.

For me is just one option - to save position on `Activity` member variable, and use it after `onActivityResult`. Maybe is possible better approach to avoid additional state creating for `Activity`?

Code example:

```java
public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
  private static final int REQ_TAKE_PICTURE = 1;

  // is it possible to avoid this variable as Activity state
  private int tempItemPosition;

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter();
    adapter.setOnItemClickListener(this::startTakePhoto);
  }

  @Override
  public void onActivityResult(int reqCode, int resCode, Intent data) {
    if(reqCode == REQ_TAKE_PICTURE) {
  updateImageItem(Uri.parse(data.getStringExtra(TakePictureActivity.RESULT_IMAGE_URI)), tempItemPosition)
    }
  }

  private void updateImageItem(Uri imageUri, int position) {
    // update item image for position
  }

  private void startTakePhoto(int position) {
    // saving state which is better to avoid
    tempItemPosition = position;
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, TakePhotoActivity.class);
    startActivityForResult(intent, REQ_TAKE_PICTURE);
  }
}

public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ViewHolder> {
  ...
  public void setOnItemClickLsitener(OnItemClickListener listener) {
    ...
  }
  ...

  public interface OnItemClickListener {
    void onItemClick(int position);
  }
}
```

Is it possible to call `updateImageItem(Uri, int)` after `onActivityResult`, but not saving clicked item position as `Activity` state?

Comment: Please be more specific, mention what do you mean by a particular term and add some code to help others understand, please read guidelines once again and update your question

Comment: @YouKnowWhoIAm question updated, added only important part of code, which involved to question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the data to the other Activity and back:

```
... your code

  @Override
  public void onActivityResult(int reqCode, int resCode, Intent data) {
    if(reqCode == REQ_TAKE_PICTURE) {
     String uriExtra = data.getStringExtra(TakePictureActivity.RESULT_IMAGE_URI);
     int positionExtra = data.getIntExtra("PhotoParentPosition")
updateImageItem(Uri.parse(uriExtra), positionExtra)
    }
  }

... your code

private void startTakePhoto(int position) {
    // saving state which is better to avoid
    tempItemPosition = position;
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, TakePhotoActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("PhotoParentPosition", position);
    startActivityForResult(intent, REQ_TAKE_PICTURE);
  }
```

In your other activity (TakePhotoActivity), you get the extra ("PhotoParentPosition") off the creation Intent and put it on the result intent.

---

Another alternative would be to use AndroidX ViewModel's and use a shared ViewModel between your two Activities.

https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel

The idea of the ViewModel is it is a data class that can hold data about your view (such as the selection list item position), this data can be saved across activitys and across configuration changes.

> Architecture Components provides ViewModel helper class for the UI controller that is responsible for preparing data for the UI. ViewModel objects are automatically retained during configuration changes so that data they hold is immediately available to the next activity or fragment instance. For example, if you need to display a list of users in your app, make sure to assign responsibility to acquire and keep the list of users to a ViewModel, instead of an activity or fragment, as illustrated by the following sample code:

Comment: Passing data through intent and back is an option if running an Activity which we have access to and can control of result. But Activity can belong to another package, such as a system camera.
In addition similar situation may occur when requesting permissions, when inside onRequestPermissionsResult we can't receive any data.
Shared ViewModel looks like a good option to prevent such difficulties.

Comment: If you are using the system camera, you should still wrap that in your own camera activity, so you can still pass the index forward and back (and hold the state in the activity you own).  This is a much cleaner code practice